# Multiple `.settings` Files Based on Configuration

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to know if there was a way to have multiple `.settings` files based on configuration that are honored at runtime. So, at the moment I have a `Settings.settings` and a `Release.settings` file under the `Properties` folder. I'm not saying this is right by any means, I'm just saying that's what I currently have.

But, when running this line of code I always get the value out of the `Settings.settings` file.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Setting
```

I realize that the `Settings` part of that line is explicitly defining the file I want, but I'm trying to find a way to get an abstracted line of code that will pull it out based off of the configuration.

So, unlike a config transform where it can be used to simply produce a different version of the file on deployment, I need to be able to actually see different values at runtime based on the configuration I'm running under.

I hope somebody can help, and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I was just wanting to do the same thing myself.

- From the Project menu, choose Add New Item. The Add New Item dialog
  box opens.
- In the Add New Item dialog box, select Settings File, type in a name
  for the file, and click Add to add a new settings file to your
  solution.
- In Solution Explorer, drag the new Settings file into the Properties
  folder. This allows your new settings to be available in code.
- Add and use settings in this file as you would any other settings
  file. You can access this group of settings via the
  Properties.Settings object.

Then you can reference each settings file by its prefix.

```
            Config config = new Config();
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                config = new Config()
                {
                    Interval = Dev.Default.Interval,
                    Username = Dev.Default.Username,
                    Password = Dev.Default.Password,
                    Directory = Dev.Default.Directory
                };
            }
            else
            {
                config = new Config()
                {
                    Interval = Settings.Default.Interval,
                    Username = Settings.Default.Username,
                    Password = Settings.Default.Password,
                    Directory = Settings.Default.Directory
                };
            }
```

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-add-multiple-sets-of-settings-to-your-application-in-csharp